# How to do logging with Spark in local mode?

Tags: logging, apache-spark

Is it possible to do logging on certain path - which will be provided as input argument - in Apache Spark while working in local mode?

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf().
  setAppName("SparkProgrammingGuide").
  setMaster(master).
  set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true").
  set("spark.eventLog.dir", "file:///home/USER")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Comment: I know you can enable event logging and path configuration through the SparkContext using the following property names: `spark.eventLog.enabled` and `spark.eventLog.dir`. The documentation for that can be found [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html). However, I'm not certain that this works in local mode.

Comment: ok. so, assuming that I create my spark context like above, how do I write in the log file afterwards?

Comment: @user706838 It's been a while since you asked this question and I wonder if you could explain what do you mean by "do logging on certain path"? Do you want to log application-specific events or Spark's?

Comment: I have run spark in local mode with `spark.eventLog.dir` parameter and the file with logs has been created. Spark History Server can be used for viewing and analyzing these logs.

Answer (score 1):

This question was already answered in the comments and independently validated.

Original answer by @Rohan

> you can enable event logging and path configuration through the
> SparkContext using the following property names:
> `spark.eventLog.enabled` and `spark.eventLog.dir`. The documentation for
> that can be found [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

Confirmation by @Yudovin

> I have run spark in local mode with `spark.eventLog.dir` parameter and
> the file with logs has been created. Spark History Server can be used
> for viewing and analyzing these logs.